# Singed into Google App with email, but phone still not showing up in list of devices during 2 step authentication setup Google

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, authentication

Please could someone help! Been trying this for hours.
[image]

iPhone not showing up in Devices that can get prompts.
I followed instruction and signed into my google account on iPhone's google app and pressed Try Again:
If you have an iPhone

1. Get the Google app from the App Store
2. Sign in with your Google Account

The phone is still not showing up on the list of devices. I tried it from Safari and Chrome.

I also even tried to do it on the iPhone from the Google App itself, and even though Im signed into my account and then chose to switch on 2 factor authentication, during the process it still does not show the phone in 'These devices can get prompts'.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the laptop is apparently what the doctor recommended!

Another thing I did that was new, was to not follow the prompt 'set up 2FA' upon logging into the Google Account. I chose 'skip'. Then went into my Security and chose to set it up through there.

FINALLY, my phone showed up in the list of devices.